# How do they remove actors' voice from anime when they dub it

Tags: audio, video, digital-audio, sound-editing

I wonder how they make dubbed version of anime and keep other sounds in background? Is it possible to remove only voice actors from audio file? I tried to download .mkv episode of an anime and tried to extract audio, so I got .aac file. Maybe there is some software that could extract it somehow and get separated voice and background sound tracks?

Comment: Sorry, but this is iff-topic here. Generally a recording source has multiple tracks which are then merged together into a combined final track. Dubbed versions typically substitute the voice track - not something you can do without the original audio tracks.  You can sort akin day badly hack it by filtering voice frequencies (nominally 100-4000hz) and dubbing over that.

Comment: Are you talking about official dubs or unofficial? Recordings start as multi-track before getting mixed into a single track, so I'm fairly sure a studio doing official dubbing would be able to receive the originals where the music and voices were separate from day 1, without needing to re-separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not something that can be done reliably. Sometimes if a voice is central in the stereo mix it is easier, e.g. https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_vocal_removal_and_isolation.html

AI software will probably get better at this over time - search for vocal remover online.

Dubbing into a different language for film/TV is generally done by having original sound/music available separately from voices, so a new mix can be created without having to remove vocals at all.